# Run many filesystem operations in parallel and asynchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, decorator

I have the following function, which returns a filesize of a file over HTTP:

```
def GetFileSize(url):
    " Function gets a url and returns it's filesize in bytes "
    url = url.replace(' ', '%20')
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    meta = u.info()
    file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
    return file_size
```

I would like to get the biggest file from a given links, and I wrote the following function for it:

```
def GetBiggestFile(links):
    " Function gets a list of links and returns the biggest file and his size in bytes "
    dic = {}
    for link in links:
        filename = link.split('/')[-1]
        filesize = GetFileSize(link)
        dic[link] = filesize
        print "%s | %.2f MB" % (filename, filesize / 1024.0 / 1024.0)

    biggest_file = max(dic, key=dic.get)
    return biggest_file, dic[biggest_file]
```

My lists have dozens of links, therefore this scripts takes some time to complete. Using threading I can fetch the different filesizes synchronously and shorten the running time of the code.

I'm not so sure how to do it - I've tried using a decorator that makes the function run asynchronously:

```
def run_async(func):
    " Decorator for running functions asynchronously. "
    from threading import Thread
    from functools import wraps

    @wraps(func)
    def async_func(*args, **kwargs):
        func_hl = Thread(target = func, args = args, kwargs = kwargs)
        func_hl.start()
        return func_hl

    return async_func
```

But I'm not sure how to make my code wait for all the answers before trying to determine who is the biggest file.

Thanks.

Comment: The usual recommended tool for this is Celery. That said, I'm having a little difficulty working out how to get started with it myself.

Comment: Also, I have edited your title. Feel free to re-edit if you think it doesn't reflect the essence of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be happier with [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

Start with this example: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Your `GetFileSize` function can be run in a process pool.

Since each process is separate, you should also have an "output Queue" into which the results are put.  A separate process does a simple "get" to retrieve all the answers from the Queue.

Comment: Getting shared nothing processes to work is often easier than getting shared everything threads to work.  There is less subtlety to processes.